# BitBucket deployment using SSH keys to remote server

Tags: ssh, yaml, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to write a YAML pipeline script to deploy files that have been altered from my bitbucket repository to my remote server using ssh keys. The document that I have in place at the moment was copied from bitbucket itself and has errors:

```
pipelines:
  default:
  - step:
      name: Deploy to test
      deployment: test
      script:
      - pipe: atlassian/sftp-deploy:0.3.1
      - variables:
         USER: $USER
         SERVER: $SERVER
         REMOTE_PATH: $REMOTE_PATH
         LOCAL_PATH: $LOCAL_PATH
```

I am getting the following error

> Configuration error
>   There is an error in your bitbucket-pipelines.yml at [pipelines > default > 0 > step > script > 1]. To be precise: Missing or empty command string. Each item in this list should either be a single command string or a map defining a pipe invocation.

My ssh public and private keys are setup in bitbucket along with the fingerprint and host. The variables have also been setup.
How do I go about setting up my YAML deploy script to connect to my remote server via ssh and transfer the files?

Answer (score 1):

Try to update the `variables` section become:

```
      - variables:
         - USER: $USER
         - SERVER: $SERVER
         - REMOTE_PATH: $REMOTE_PATH
         - LOCAL_PATH: $LOCAL_PATH
```

Here is am example about how to set `variables`: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/configure-bitbucket-pipelines-yml-792298910.html#Configurebitbucket-pipelines.yml-ci_variablesvariables

Answer (score 0):

Your directive **- step** has to be intended.
I have bitbucket-pipelines.yml like that (using rsync instead of ssh):

```
# This is a sample build configuration for PHP.
# Check our guides at https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/e8YWN for more examples.
# Only use spaces to indent your .yml configuration.
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
image: php:7.2.1-fpm

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script:
          - apt-get update 
          - apt-get install zip -y
          - apt-get install unzip -y
          - apt-get install libgmp3-dev -y
          - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
          - composer install
          - cp .env.example .env
          #- vendor/bin/phpunit 
          - pipe: atlassian/rsync-deploy:0.2.0
            variables:
                USER: $DEPLOY_USER
                SERVER: $DEPLOY_SERVER
                REMOTE_PATH: $DEPLOY_PATH
                LOCAL_PATH: '.'
```

I suggest to use their online editor in repository for editing *bitbucket-pipelines.yml*, it checks all formal yml structure and you can't commit invalid file.
Even if you check file on some other yaml editor, it may look fine, but not necessary  according to bitbucket specification. Their online editor does fine job.

Also, I suggest to visit their community on [atlasian community](https://community.atlassian.com) as it's very active, sometimes their staff members are providing answers.

However, I struggle with plenty dependencies needed to run tests properly. (actual bitbucket-pipelines.yml is becoming bigger and bigger).
Maybe there is some nicely prepared Docker image for this job.